# Java Console closes too on startup, so it's impossible to see what startup error may jnlp app has. How to see its output?

Tags: java, jnlp, java-console

I'm running a Java application as a jnlp and sometimes, when a problem occurs during startup it will spit something out to the Java Console and close. But it closes so fast that I can't actually see anything at all.

Is there some way to see this log, maybe in a file on disk? Or to avoid the closing of this console window?

Thanks

Comment: Look at the Oracle documentation here : https://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could activate the tracing in the java configuration.

```
advanced -> activate Tracing.
```

once this is done it writes Tracing files in the folder

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\log
```

There you could inspect what caused the error in the jnlp